# Restore postgres in command line on ubuntu failed

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, psql

This question may be asked many times. We are trying to move a postgres db from windows (psql 9.3) to ubuntu runing postgres 9.3. Here is what we did:

1. In windows, create backup for db cis with pgadmin. The backup file name is cis.backup
2. Copy the cis.backup to ubuntu and save it under /home/myname
3. Log in to psql with: `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`
4. Create db cis_new on ubuntu with `#CREATE DATABASE cis_new WITH OWNER postgres ENCODING 'UTF8';`
5. Restore `#pg_restore --dbname cis_new --verbose /home/myname/cis.backup`

The last pg_restore creates nothing and there was no restore at all. Is anything we missed here? Thanks.

Comment: Post the Error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `#pg_restore --dbname cis_new --verbose /home/myname/cis.backup`

The hash is not part of the command name. It's a convention on unix systems used to indicate "root prompt". Unfortunately, it's also *a comment* on some shells.

Try again without the hash.

Comment: Did you mean # sign? # was not included for pg_restore when it was typed in.

Comment: You are right. The pg_restore should be ran under linux. Also we added linux root as pg superuser before running the pg_restore.

Comment: Adding a 'root' user is unnecessary. Just `sudo -u postgres pg_restore ...`  . As for running under linux vs windows, it should not matter at all. I'm glad your issue is resolved but that isny why.